# Why this combination of flat and sort methods is returning sub arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to declare a function that sorts arrays/subarrays as below:

1. `sortIt([4, 1, 3])` ➞ [1, 3, 4]
2. `sortIt([[4], [1], [3]])` ➞ [[1], [3], [4]]
3. `sortIt([4, [1], 3])` ➞ [[1], 3, 4]
4. `sortIt([[4], 1, [3]])` ➞ [1, [3], [4]]
5. `sortIt([[3], 4, [2], [5], 1, 6])` ➞ [1, [2], [3], 4, [5], 6]

I came up with this solution but I don't get why it works for all the cases:

```
function sortIt(arr) {
    return newArr = arr.flat(arr).sort((a,b)=> a-b)
}
```

For example, at bullet point 5, the function as declared should return the following array [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]. I am using flat so I would have thought that the subarrays would have been removed.

What am I missing?

#edit:

I need to get the array sorted without being flattened.
The code I came up with is working but I don't get why.

As Emanuele kindly pointed out my function should return a flattened array but it doesn't, it maintains the sub-arrays and I don't get why.

Comment: `arr.flat(arr)` what is this supposed to do?

Comment: Also, it's quite unnecessary to assign to `newArr` in the `return`.

Comment: do you want a flat array or keeping the structure, but sorted?

Comment: I'm confised - your expected output on each item still has the nested arrays but your final paragraph (and your code) implies you want the result flattened

Answer (score 2):

You can do as below, as long as you want the result to still have the nested array style.

```js
function sortIt(arr){
  return arr.sort((a, b) => (Array.isArray(a) ? a[0] : a) - (Array.isArray(b) ? b[0] : b));  
}

console.log(sortIt([4, 1, 3]))
console.log(sortIt([[4], [1], [3]]))
console.log(sortIt([4, [1], 3]))
console.log(sortIt([[4], 1, [3]]))
console.log(sortIt([[3], 4, [2], [5], 1, 6]) )
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort the outer array but take a flat approach for the inner values

```js
const
    sortIt = array => array.sort((a, b) =>
        [].concat(a)[0] - [].concat(b)[0]
    );

console.log(sortIt([4, 1, 3]));                // [1, 3, 4]
console.log(sortIt([[4], [1], [3]]));          // [[1], [3], [4]]
console.log(sortIt([4, [1], 3]));              // [[1], 3, 4]
console.log(sortIt([[4], 1, [3]]));            // [1, [3], [4]]
console.log(sortIt([[3], 4, [2], [5], 1, 6])); // [1, [2], [3], 4, [5], 6]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Also isn't going to flatten `array` itself. The result will still be an array with other arrays inside it.

Comment: @Jamiec, now it shoulf work for all cases, if op does not want a flat array.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you pass `arr` as argument of `flat` method (see [flat method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)).
What about this:

```
function sortIt(arr) {
    return arr.flat().sort();
}
console.log(sortIt([[3], 4, [2], [5], 1, 6]))
```

and the result is

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```